# Angular 2: How to use input [(ngModel)] value in Component?

Tags: javascript, angular

Sorry if this is a basic question but I can't seem to figure it out.

Basically, I want to take an `[(ngModel)]` input value from the template and then pass it along to my component. I feel like this is pretty basic Angular 2 stuff but I can't seem to get it.

My code:

`input.html`:

```
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

---

`app/app.component.html`

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value1">
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value2">
<!--I want my function value to update every time [(ngModel)] is updated
{{someFunction}}
```

---

`app/app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  someFunction(): number {
     // I want to pass value1 and value 2 here from my ngModel in my template
     return value1 * value2
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare these variables in your component.

```
export class AppComponent {
  value1: number;
  value2: number;
  someFunction() {
     return this.value1 * this.value2;
 } 
}
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mpNLTBt28vGXecqe6ilz?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect! I will accept this answer as correct after the time limit is up. 

I have one more question: Can I set the returned value of this function as a variable that I can then use as my template? For example, set the value of `someFunction() = value3`, and then use `{{value3}}` in my template?

Comment: Angular provides you 2-way binding. You can either use the function directly on your template, for example {{someFunction()}}, either declare another variable like result and print its value into your template. Then by making someFunction() void and replacing return this.value1 * this.value2; with this.result = this.value1 * this.value2 you will have an updated value of result in your template.

Comment: This works as expected, though I'm unclear how to go back to having the returned value be updated each time an `ngModel` value is changed, instead of binding the function to `(click)`.

Comment: @user3183717 You can use e.g. `keyup` event and bind it to the each `input`. The value will be updated dynamically.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! If I didn't want to bind it to (keyup), would it be better to just do {{someFunction()}} then?

Comment: @user3183717 I would suggest to use `events` and functions instead of calling it this way, but I think that doesn't matter which method you choose, it won't have a big impact on your app performance.